# Check webpage's X-Frame-Options in Java

Tags: java, php

I already did something like this in PHP, but I need it in Java. This is my actual PHP code:

```
$error = false;
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
  CURLOPT_URL            => "http://google.com/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $httpCode['header_size']);

if(stripos($headers, 'X-Frame-Options: DENY') > -1 || 
   stripos($headers, 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN')) {
  $error = true;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

So `$error` is `false`, but when webpage has set to disable embedding in iframe, it will set to `true`, so I know, that this webpage is not embeddable.

All I have in Java is this:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://google.com/").openConnection();
```

What I have to do in Java to get same results as in PHP?